# WPF дизайнер ругается на отсутствие конструктора по умолчанию

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, wpf-blendability

Когда для дизайнера указываю в `DataContext` `VM-ку` у которой нет конструктора по умолчанию то он всегда на это ругается. Как можно исправить эту ситуацию?

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:AuthenticationVm,
                                          IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если указать `IsDesignTimeCreatable=False`?

Comment: @VladD, Хмм, помогло. А какие различия если ставить `true` или `false`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если у вас указано `IsDesignTimeCreatable=True`, дизайнер WPF попытается создать объект этого класса, и использовать в качестве `DataContext` для отображения. Для этого ему нужен конструктор без параметров.

Если у вас указано `IsDesignTimeCreatable=False`, дизайнер WPF не будет пытаться создать объект. Вместо этого он создаст свой фейковый тип данных с такими же открытыми свойствами, инстанциирует его, и будет использовать в качестве `DataContext`'а.

---

Когда вы указываете `IsDesignTimeCreatable=False`, вы больше не будеет видеть в дизайнере данные. Это может быть не очень удобно. Вот более продвинутый способ, который позволяет видеть данные в дизайнере даже если у вашей VM нет конструктора без аргументов.

Для этого нужно создать *данные для дизайнера*. Допустим, у нас есть такой VM-класс:

```
class VM
{
    public VM(string text) { Text = text; } 
    public string Text { get; }
}
```

Как мы видим, у этого класса нет конструктора без параметров, и у его свойства нету сеттера. Это нам не помеха.

Заводим в проекте ResourceDictionary (пусть он называется `DesignDictionary.xaml`, точное название не важно). Когда вы его создадите, он будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyCoolProject">

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Удалите всё это (!) и положите вместо него объявление экземпляра вашего VM-класса:

```
<local:VM xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyCoolProject" Text="Design Text"/>
```

Теперь зайдите в свойства файла, и задайте ему `Build Action = DesignData` и удалите `Custom Tool`:

[image: design data]

Теперь этот экземпляр можно использовать следующим образом:

```
<Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=DesignDictionary.xaml}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
</Grid>
```

Не забудьте перекомпилировать проект. Теперь в дизайнере отображаются данные:

[image: результат налицо]

Всё, мы обошли ограничения дизайнера WPF.

Литература: MSDN/WPF Designer blog/[Sample Data in the WPF and Silverlight Designer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsldesigner/2010/06/30/sample-data-in-the-wpf-and-silverlight-designer/).

---

Ещё одной идеей для борьбы с проблемой может быть создание специального производного класса (только для использования в дизайнере), в котором будет конструктор по умолчанию. Этот конструктор будет вызывать базовый конструктор с какими-нибудь подходящими параметрами. Чтобы случайно не использовать этот класс в реальном коде, можно дать ему атрибут `[Obsolete]`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: @Lightness: Посмотрите в обновление ответа, добавил ещё один интересный вариант.

Comment: Интересные подходы! Спасибо!

Comment: @VladD, а можно ли сделать конструктор без параметров только для `DesignInstance`, чтобы случайно не воспользоваться им в коде?

Comment: @S.Kost: Можно. Поставьте ему атрибут `[Obsolete]`.

Comment: @VladD, помечает как "устаревший", но все равно компилируется если вызвать его. Спасибо за совет. Оказывается это было в ответе, я не заметил)