# Локализация проекта, не отображаются данные в дизайнере форм WPF VS2019

Tags: c#, wpf, локализация

Занимаюсь локализацией  проекта основу взял [здесь](https://itnan.ru/post.php?c=1&p=274477). Тестовый проект сработал полностью вопросов нет, но при переносе в свой проект  в дизайнере отсутствуют какие либо ссылки на элементы файлов ресурсов, к примеру при привязке `Content`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это отображение в дизайнере форм,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так отображается в запущенном приложении.
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть причина
Разметка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код бехайнд неиспользуется

Тестовый проект окно выглядит следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Разметка `

```
<Window x:Class="WpfLocalization.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfLocalization"
        xmlns:globalization="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfLocalization.Localization"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type={x:Type local:MainViewModel}}"
        Title="{l:Localization WindowTitle}"
        MinWidth="300" MinHeight="200"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="AbcStrings" Type="system:String">
            <system:String>A</system:String>
            <system:String>B</system:String>
            <system:String>C</system:String>
        </x:Array>
        
        <Style x:Key="ExStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{l:Localization World}" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{l:Localization 'Localization'}" />

        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                  SelectedIndex="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding CultureInfos}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentCulture, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type globalization:CultureInfo}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{l:Localization KeyBinding={Binding ThreeLetterISOLanguageName}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    `
```

Но при переносе решения  проект отображение имен свойств пропадает (не удобно для отладки)
Евгений посоветовал инициализировать FallBackValue в точке останова на рисунке оно установленно. Как заставить его отображаться.   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите разметку и код.

Comment: А что вы ожидаете, чтоб дизайнер сам угадал что за тип у вас там, какое значение и так далее? Тогда бы некоторые проекты очень сильно грузили бы студию, получая постоянно нужные данные. По этой причине (и некоторым другим), студия абстрагируется от реальных данных, делая лишь наброски с именами переменных либо простой пустоты.

Comment: Вы можете сами заполнить дизайнер фейковыми данными, для этого каждый привязанный класс должен иметь пустой конструктор с данными по умолчанию для каждого свойства, а в XAML установить `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance тип, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"`, тогда вы будете видеть все эти данные по умолчанию. Либо вы можете сделать [файл ресурсов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/569974/220553), который также будет принят как источник данных для дизайнера.

Comment: Разметку или код принято вставлять текстом в пост. Скриншоты кода - не формат для StackOverflow. Но вашем случае это не так критично, я поддерживаю оба комментария, что выше даны, это по сути и есть ответ.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ "А что вы ожидаете, чтоб дизайнер сам угадал что за тип у вас там, какое значение и так далее? Тогда бы некоторые проекты очень сильно грузили бы студию, получая постоянно нужные данные. По этой причине (и некоторым другим), студия абстрагируется от реальных данных, делая лишь наброски с именами переменных либо простой пустоты. " 
Мне и нужны наброски с именами свойств в место пустоты  в дизайнере, а то колеги подумают что ничего нет.

Comment: Напишите значение по умолчанию для этого "кружка" (что-то вроде `{Binding Lang, FallbackValue=LNG}`, можете еще `TargetNullValue` указать), тогда у вас будет выводить это значение (в моем примере `LNG`) в дизайнере. Я думаю, это самый оптимальный и менее затратный вариант для вас.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Во первых, спасибо БОЛЬШОЕ за то, что возитесь со мной. На скрине (последнем в точке останова) видно что значение для FallBackValue установленно, вот его то я и хочу увидеть, но не получается

Answer (score 1):

В общем после долгих поисков причины, как то увидел что у других товарищей по проекту все отлично отрабатывается, переустановка вижлы и загруска заново проекта с гита отлично решила мою проблему