# Отображение скрытого элемента в дизайнере XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть следующая строка кода (XAML):

```
<Label Visibility="{Binding Path=IsTextVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Content="Sample text"/>
```

Смысл в том, чтобы отображать ее только в том случае, когда свойство модели IsTextVisible истинно. И это прекрасно работает

Вопрос: можно ли включить отображение этого контрола в дизайнере XAML?

Comment: `d:Visibility="Visible"`

Comment: Ошибка XDG0032 Свойство "Visibility" не существует в пространстве имен "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008".

Comment: Чтож вы используете старое... Ну делайте тогда набор данных для дизайнера, примерно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/569974/220553).