# Расположение объекта xaml в отдельный файл проекта

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Доброго времени суток всем)

Не знаю, как точно сформулировать свой вопрос, поэтому попытаюсь описать его очень детально.

У меня есть в проекта `xaml`-код основного окна, и, соответственно, там же расположен визуальный редактор. У меня есть задача нарисовать достаточное большое кол-во разных фигур (и в будущем их число будет увеличиваться). Все эти фигуры будут вызываться в ходе работы программы в нном кол-ве. Я хотел бы(если что-то подобное в VS вообще есть), сохранять каждую фигуры в отдельный `xaml` файл, и позже их использовать програмно.

Я мог бы нарисовать все эти фигуры в основном коде `xaml`, и поставить `Visible=Collapsed`, а позже копировать эти фигуры в коде, и изменять их размер и изображение. Но этот способ максимально недубен. К тому же, не хотелось бы все фигуры хранить в основном коде `xaml`, чтобы не нагружать этот код.

И сразу вторую часть вопроса хотел бы задать. Если способ хранить фигуры в отдельных `xaml` файлах (которые будут расположены в папке в моей текущем проекте) есть (в чем я почти уверен, просто не знаю, как это сделать), то есть ли возможность добавлять отдельные `xaml` файлы в проект, но вместе с их визуальным редактором?

(Как я себе это представляю, чисто теоретически):

Я кликаю ЛКМ на папку в проекте, нажимаю добавить. Далее я выбираю что-то, что добавит мне `xaml` код с визуальным редактором. (как `xaml` код с редактором окна, только без связи с програмной частю, пока-что я сам не задействую `xaml`-код програмно).

Вооот. Надеюсь я смог адекватно объяснить свою мысль. Спасибо большой тем, кто дочитал сюда:)

Буду очень благодарен, если кто сможет как-то помочь.

Comment: ИМХО, вы совершенно не в том направлении думаете. Отделите визуальную часть, от данных, а уже затем с данными и работайте. Допустим фигура, что это? Набор данных по типу `цвет`, `размер`, `положение` и др. Данные в C# где хранятся? Правильно, в простых классах, ну так и делайте класс со всеми этими свойствами, затем сделайте коллекцию таких классов, ну а в XAML просто привяжите это все, чтобы тот разметил так, как надо это. Хранение тоже тогда простое - сериализация, например в JSON, будет тогда текстовый файл с простой JSON строкой. Но XAML... Не в его обязанностях хранить.

Comment: XAML используется для разметки интерфейса до компиляции приложения. Во время работы рендерить XAML тоже технически возможно, но это не то, чем стоит заниматься, есть куча других, более простых способов хранения данных. Поддерживаю комментарий выше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вам покажу самый простейший вариант того, как размещать всякие фигуры правильно в WPF проекте, без мудрения с сохранением XAML и прочего.

**Суть** - отделить данные от визуальной части, вот просто представьте, что вы рисуете, к примеру в фотошопе, вы запускаете программу, грузите .psd файл, программа прогружает все слои, все ваши рисунки, наброски, и прочее. Сейчас же, вы пытаетесь, грубо говоря сохранить сделанный вами снимок экрана, на котором был запущен фотошоп и нарисована картинка. Согласитесь, звучит бредово. Вот и ваша задумка с сохранение XAML тоже, весьма странная, ведь XAML создан для того, чтобы вывести конкретный объект так задумал его разработчик, а не как формат для хранения данных.

Ок, поняв суть проблемы, давайте реализовывать задумку:

1. Создадим простой класс, в котором будет храниться та информация, которая нужна нам для вывода объекта на экран, допустим это будет цвет и положение (X/Y), фигура пока пусть будет простой круг:

   ```
    public class Circle
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public Brush Fill { get; set; }
    }
   ```

   Как видите, примитивные данные, ничего лишнего.
2. Теперь сделаем коллекцию в виде свойства, в которую сразу добавим несколько наших кругов, писать это будет прям в классе окна, но вам советую сделать отдельный класс для данных:

   ```
    public List<Circle> Shapes { get; set; } = new()
    {
        new(){ Fill = Brushes.Black, X = 0, Y = 0 },
        new(){ Fill = Brushes.Red, X = 30, Y = 30 },
        new(){ Fill = Brushes.Green, X = 60, Y = 60 },
        new(){ Fill = Brushes.Purple, X = 90, Y = 90 },
    };
   ```

   Обратите внимание, это свойство, ведь привязка доступна только к публичным свойствам. Также заметьте, тут простой `List<>`, если вы будете добавлять данные в момент работы приложения, то лучше заменить на `ObservableCollection<>`, иначе интерфейс не будет оповещаться об изменениях.
3. Теперь надо окну задать источник данных, из которого он будет брать свойства для привязки, пишем прям в конструкторе, после инициализации `DataContext = this;`, но опять, это чисто примитивный пример, так лучше не делать на практике, класс окна у вас должен быть чистым, а `DataContext` задан до момента инициализации окна ([почему и как](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553)).
4. Супер, у нас есть теперь данные, осталось вывести их на экран. Открываем XAML окна и пишем нечто такое:

   ```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse
                    Width="30"
                    Height="30"
                    Fill="{Binding Fill}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
   ```

   Здесь мы берем `ItemsControl`, который выводит все объекты коллекции на экран и привязываем его к нашей созданной коллекции; далее задаем через `ItemTemplate` нужный вид с привязкой к нужным свойствам; далее через `ItemsPanel` задаем панель, на который будут размещены объекты (`Canvas`); ну и последнее, через `ItemContainerStyle` задаем им позицию на `Canvas`.

Запускаем, смотрим на результат:

[image: Result]

Как видите, мы без проблем отделили данные от визуальной части, нам не нужно теперь лезть в XAML для того, чтобы добавить, к примеру новый круг, все это просто делается добавлением нового объекта в коллекцию.

**Как нам улучшить приложение, если должно быть несколько фигур?**
А по сути также, только нам надо сделать еще один класс, вынести общую логику в абстракцию/интерфейс, ну и дополнить XAML.

1. Вынесем в интерфейс всю общую информацию фигуры. Допустим, мы хотим сделать квадрат, что у него общего с кругом? Цвет, позиция, по сути, в моем примере он дублирует ранее созданный нами класс `Circle`, давайте тогда вынесем это в `interface`

   ```
    public interface IShape
    {
        public double X { get; }
        public double Y { get; }
        public Brush Fill { get; }
    }
   ```
2. Унаследуем круг от созданного интерфейса:

   ```
    public class Circle : IShape
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public Brush Fill { get; set; }
    }
   ```
3. Создадим новый класс, допустим квадрат, который также будет унаследован от `IShape`:

   ```
    public class Square : IShape
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public Brush Fill { get; set; }
    }
   ```
4. Изменим коллекцию объектов, пусть там будет несколько квадратов и кругов, а сама коллекция будет уже `List<IShape>`:

   ```
    public List<IShape> Shapes { get; set; } = new()
    {
        new Circle(){ Fill = Brushes.Black, X = 0, Y = 0 },
        new Circle(){ Fill = Brushes.Red, X = 30, Y = 30 },
        new Square(){ Fill = Brushes.Green, X = 60, Y = 60 },
        new Square(){ Fill = Brushes.Purple, X = 90, Y = 90 },
    };
   ```
5. Теперь XAML, нам надо вынести вид объектов из `ItemTemplate` в ресурсы:

   1. Удаляем `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>`, запомнив его `DataTemplate`.
   2. Пишем на его месте `<ItemsControl.Resources>` и помещаем внутрь `DataTemplate`. Вы можете поместить их в ресурсы окна, задав окну (`Window.Resources`), или можете поместить в `App.xaml` файл, что будет ресурсом приложения, либо вообще вынести в отдельный проект, это уже решайте сами. Должно быть примерно следующее:

      ```
      <ItemsControl.Resources>
          <DataTemplate>
              <Ellipse
                  Width="30"
                  Height="30"
                  Fill="{Binding Fill}" />
          </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.Resources>
      ```
6. Вынеся нужный вид в ресурсы, мы теперь можем их задавать под тип входного объекта, делается это при помощи указания `DataType` у `DataTemplate`. Давайте пропишем квадрату и кругу все нужное:

   ```
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Circle}">
            <Ellipse
                Width="30"
                Height="30"
                Fill="{Binding Fill}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Square}">
            <Rectangle 
                Width="30"
                Height="30"
                Fill="{Binding Fill}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
   ```

Запускаем, смотрим результат:

[image: Result 2]

Как видите, теперь у нас 2 фигуры, данные которых в одном месте, а вид в другом. Имея все это, вы теперь без проблем сможете выбрать нужный вам тип хранения, будь то база данных, или простая сериализация в конкретный тип, это уже решайте сами, главное, не работайте с XAML, как с источником данных. Если вам нужно видеть эти изменения и в дизайнере студии, то для этого задайте окну `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:MainWindow}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"`, где `IsDesignTimeCreatable` - это подгрузка реальных данных, но учтите, этот способ может сильно нагрузить студию, особенно когда данных много. Чтобы не грузить все данные, можете сделать специальные [данные для дизайнера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/569974/220553).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Когда задавал вопрос не ожидал получить такой большой и качественный ответ, и все это еще простыми словами. Очень просто и подробно разъяснили. Еще раз спасибо.