# Как сделать чтобы при добавлении элементов в ItemsControl двигалась кнопка?

Tags: c#, wpf

у меня возник нюанс мне нужно чтобы при добавлении элемента кнопка сдвигалась.
[image]

Сейчас кнопка находиться  не на правильной позиции,она должна быть возле элементов  и двигаться при добавлены нового элемента(покажу как должно выглядеть это в следующей картинке).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть при нажатии  нужно чтобы  элемент  добавляться а кнопка   сдвигалась если нет  элементов будет видна только кнопка.

**Мой код XAML:**

```
<StackPanel >
                    <TextBlock Text="Filter Files"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Foreground="White" FontSize="20"
                               />
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Filters,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                               
                                <Border CornerRadius="3"  BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" Margin="2">
                                    <Grid Margin="5">
                                        <TextBlock Width="50" Height="20" Foreground="White"
                                               Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        <Border
                                        Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                        Background="#FFFF2020"
                                        CornerRadius="3">
                                            <Border.InputBindings>
                                                <MouseBinding
                                          Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.RemoveFilterCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                          Gesture="LeftClick" />
                                            </Border.InputBindings>

                                            <TextBlock
                                             Margin="1"
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                             Foreground="White"
                                             Text="" />
                                            <!--Style="{StaticResource BaseText}"-->
                                        </Border>

                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>

                    <Button Width="50" Height="20" Content="Add Item" Command="{Binding}"/>
                </StackPanel>
```

Подскажите  такое возможно реализовать ?

Comment: Костыль, но как вариант: Сделайте интерфейс, в нем сделайте свойство, например `Text`, которое будет отвечать за текст кнопки, также свойство `ICommand` для самой команды закрытия. Имея интерфейс, сделайте 2 класса: 1. Для самих этих расширений. 2. Для типа кнопки. После, сделайте коллекцию этих интерфейсов, добавляя туда нужные элементы, а последним кнопку. В XAML, через `DataContext` задайте вид для двух классов, где классу кнопки делаете вид, естественно, последней кнопки, а классу расширений текущий вид объектов. Таким образом, кнопка у вас будет как часть коллекции.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у вас случайно нету примера похожего?

Comment: Ну [вот допустим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1430956/220553), только у вас будет не круг и квадрат, а текущий ваш вид расширений и вид кнопки добавления.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо вам огромное,ценю вашу помощь. Вопрос если объекты будут  реализовать разные  интерфейсы как быть ?

Comment: А в чем трудности с разными интерфейсами? Интерфейс - это контракт, который должен соблюдать конкретный объект. Если ваш объект должен соблюдать несколько контрактов, один из которых именно кнопка в UI, то пишите несколько интерфейсов, логика UI и добавления кнопок не изменится.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  как в коллекцию `List<IShape>`  добавлю   объекты  с разной реализацией интерфейсов

Comment: `list.Add(new Circle());`, `list.Add(new Square());`. Коллекция `list` - это `List<IShape>` (коллекция интерфейсов), а `Circle` и `Square` это реализующие интерфейс классы (`public class Square : IShape { ... }`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это понял что вы написали,если  `Square : IShape` а   `Circle:IFigure` как мне быть?

Comment: Яж уже сказал выше, вы можете навешать сколько угодно интерфейсов, сделайте один конкретный, который будет отвечать за конкретную задачу, ну и делайте далее `Square : IShape`, `Circle : IShape, IFigure`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я вас понял спасибо огромное