# Свойства линии не привязываются к ViewModel WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Необходимо, чтобы при изменении координаты линии свойство передовалось во ViewModel (координаты линии изменяются при перемещении курсора).

MainWindow.xaml
`<Canvas Name="test" Background="Transparent" MouseMove="test_MouseMove"></Canvas>`
MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Line line;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            line = new Line
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                X1 = 100,
                Y1 = 0,
            };
            test.Children.Add(line);
            var viewModel = new ViewModel();
            var myBinding = new Binding
            {
                Source = viewModel,
                Path = new PropertyPath("X2"),
                UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
            };
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.X2Property, myBinding);
        }

        private void test_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var point = e.GetPosition(this);
            line.X2 = point.X;
            line.Y2 = point.Y;
        }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
internal class ViewModel
{
    private double x2;
    public double X2 
    { 
        get
        { 
            return x2; 
        }
        set
        {
            x2 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ужасный код, нарушающий все возможные правила. Если вы делаете по принципам MVVM, то у вас его нет. 1. View не должна знать ничего про VM и M слои, а у вас прям создается в окне (View слое) класс `ViewModel`, вынесите это **за** пределы окна и подключите к окну как `DataContext`, не нужно ничего городить больше. 2. Ни в коем случае не создавайте и не управляйте элементами View через код, у вас для этого есть XAML, в котором все это и указывается. Вот этого `test.Children.Add(line);` вообще быть не должно. 3. Привязка аналогично, в XAML сделали `{Binding свойство}` и все, не надо в коде.

Comment: У вас должно быть что-то типа [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1430956/220553), любую фигуру так прописывайте и реализовывайте ей любое поведение, ну и окну задаете [DataContext](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553), все, почти ни единой строки C# кода...

Comment: 1. Вроде View может знать про ViewModel, так как при присваивании к DataContext ViewModel, View уже про него знает, а вот ViewModel ничего не должен знать про View. 2. Если у меня линии создаются во время выполнения (например какой-нибудь редактор блок-схем) тот test.Children.Add(line) необходим. Мне необходимо сделать привязку через код c#.

Comment: 1. Вы не поняли о чем я. Вот условно `class MainWindow { public MainWindow() { DataContext = new VM(); } }` или `var window = new MainWindow { DataContext = new VM() }`, два способа установки свойства, где в первом случае окно даже и не скомпилируется, если удалить класс VM, а в другом случае, мы снаружи устанавливаем это свойство, и о нем знает только внешний класс, не View. Почитайте ссылку, которую я дал выше. 2. "необходим" - ошибаетесь, я вам также дал ссылку, где я хоть одну строку C# там написал? Вы такого не найдете, но на экране у меня вдруг 4 круга, как? Внимание на `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, так действительно лучше.

Comment: А подскажи пожалуйста как теперь обратиться к canvas если я хочу сохранить изображение (png) фигур на нём.  

<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <Canvas />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881865/saving-a-wpf-canvas-as-an-image как в данном примере

Comment: Отдельный вопрос задайте.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1541235/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D1%84-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8E-img-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0-wpf-c