# Добавление элементов в блок (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

я новичок в WPF и столкнулся с такой вот проблемой.
У меня есть разметка такого типа:

```
<DockPanel>
<DockPanel Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="150">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="/View/Windows/roll_up.png"/>
                <TextBox    Style="{StaticResource PropText}" Height="35"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
<Button>Добавить</Button>
</DocPanel>
```

Первый DockPanel является контейнером.

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в контейнер добавлялись новый DockPanel с содержимым указанным выше в коде, а кнопка Добавить была всегда в самом конце

Может есть статьи как такое реализовать? Или есть уже готовый код?
Данные о картинках и тексте будут храниться в базе данных.
Спасибо!!!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1430956/220553