# Создание TextBox с наименованием

Tags: c#, wpf, элементы-управления

У меня имеется много TextBox полей, к каждому из которых имеется свой TextBlock с названием поля. Из-за того, что XAML разрастается до невероятных размеров, а все что указывается в TextBlock - это поле Text (остальное забил общим стилем). Назрел вопрос: как бы сделать элемент управления состоящий из TextBox и TextBlock с форматированием, имеющий в себе все свойства TextBox + поле Text для TextBlock.
Пробовал создать его через UserControl, но в таком случае нужно прописывать очень много. Поэтому хотелось бы как-то унаследовать от TextBox.
Если кто знает как - пожалуйста кодом. Спасибо.

Comment: `нужно прописывать очень много` - чего это например? Что `TextBox`, что `TextBlock` - важное там только одно - `Text` свойство, которое вам достаточно пробросить через свойство зависимости. `имеется много TextBox полей` - а вот это означает лишь одно - вы делаете странное, ибо если много, значит это коллекция, которая имеет все нужные данные и которая привязана к одному `ItemsControl` с нужным видом. Если вы коллекцию вручную расписываете в XAML, то чтож, вы ССЗБ (гуглите).

Comment: Ага, понял. У меня просто не так много опыта. Я просто не допер до такой вещи, как обращаться к элементам пользовательского элемента по имени. Так что просто создал два свойства для текстов и задал имена. А на счет кастомного ItemsControl - тут надо будет разобраться.

Comment: Я вам и слова не говорил про обращение по имени... Это самое ужасное, что можно только сделать в WPF) Привязки - вот ваш главный инструмент, пользуйтесь только им. Если видите в коде `textBox.Text = ...` или аналог - значит вы делаете что-то не так.

Comment: Нет я имею ввиду, что в XAML я пишу что-то вроде:
`<local:TestElement x:Name="TestElement" Text="Text" Header="Header" />`
А в коде если надо обратиться к тому же TextBox (что-то изменить) через
`TestElement.TBox.Height = 22;` (где TBox собственно имя в TextBox в пользовательском элементе)

Comment: Точней там будет `Text="{Binding Text}" Header="{Binding Header}"`

Comment: `А в коде если надо обратиться к тому же TextBox (что-то изменить) через TestElement.TBox.Height = 22;`, а потом перечитываем мой комментарий выше `Если видите в коде textBox.Text = ... или аналог - значит вы делаете что-то не так.`... У вас **вообще** не должно быть `x:Name`, вот вообще, от слова совсем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Пример

Предположим, у нас есть такой вид

[image: UI]

Написан он следующим образом

XAML

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Margin="5">
        <TextBlock x:Name="name1" FontWeight="Medium" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Лет: " />
            <TextBox x:Name="age1" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Margin="5">
        <TextBlock x:Name="name2" FontWeight="Medium" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Лет: " />
            <TextBox x:Name="age2" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Margin="5">
        <TextBlock x:Name="name3" FontWeight="Medium" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Лет: " />
            <TextBox x:Name="age3" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Margin="5">
        <TextBlock x:Name="name4" FontWeight="Medium" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Лет: " />
            <TextBox x:Name="age4" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        name1.Text = "Вася";
        age1.Text = "13";

        name2.Text = "Петя";
        age2.Text = "18";

        name3.Text = "Маша";
        age3.Text = "7";

        name4.Text = "Оля";
        age4.Text = "24";
    }
}
```

Многие новички именно так и пишут свой проект, не задумываясь о правильности того, что они делают. Ну а делают они все в корне неверно, ибо самое ключевое в WPF проекте, это XAML и Binding (привязки), если вы ими пренебрегаете, вы очень многого лишаетесь, как в плане удобства, так и в плане производительности.

#### Как поступить

Первым делом давайте взглянем на вид и подумаем, а не коллекция случаем это? Ведь если что-то имеет повторяющиеся "паттерны", то значит это можно описать одним классом и создать его множество раз, поместив в коллекцию, верно? Сделаем это, получив уже такой C# код:

```
public record User(string Name, int Age);

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Users = [new("Вася", 13), new("Петя", 18), new("Маша", 7), new("Оля", 24)];
    }
}
```

Смотрите какой простой и логичный код, где есть конкретный класс `User`, имеющее в себе только те данные, которые относятся к конкретному человеку. А также есть простая коллекция `Users`, которая хранит в себе всех этих людей.

Имея коллекцию, давайте теперь адаптируем под нее XAML. За вывод коллекции отвечает `ListBox` (если нужно выделение) и `ItemsControl` (если выделение нам не нужно), также есть всякие `DataGrid` и пр., которые имеют разный вид отображения коллекции. В данном случае нам нужно просто продублировать определенный вид столько раз, сколько объектов в коллекции, а значит подойдет простой `ItemsControl`. XAML превратится тогда в такое:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="5">
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Medium" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Лет: " />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Заметьте, все дубликаты ушли, я только раз написал нужный мне вид и привязал его к коллекции, ничего более.

Чтобы это все заработало, нам надо указать `DataContext` окну, это некий источник данных, в котором будут искаться все свойства для привязки. В коде выше, коллекцию я создал прям в классе окна, это плохо, лучше вынести в отдельный класс, но для примера сойдет, ну а раз данные у нас в окне, то и указываем окну в конструкторе `DataContext = this;`.

Как все сделали, запускаем проект и видим все тот-же вид, который и был, с тем-же набором данных, но уже написанный правильно, с использованием привязок. Обратите внимание, в XAML у меня нет **ни одного `x:Name`**.

#### UserControl или как сделать `TextBox` с наименованием

Поняв теперь как избавиться от дубликатов в коде, можно "сгруппировать" вид нашего "юзера" в один конкретный `UserControl`, делается это очень просто:

1. Кликаем ПКМ на название проекта и выбираем "Добавить" - "Пользовательский элемент управления.
2. Задаем ему нужное имя, в моем случае это будет просто `UserView`.
3. Открываем `.xaml.cs` файл и пишем там после конструктора `propdp` и жмем TAB, вам студия вставит заготовку для свойства зависимости.
4. Указываем этому свойству тип, имя, название `UserControl`, значение по умолчанию.
5. В моем примере, я сделаю 2 свойство, заголовок и значение, получится следующее

   ```
   public string Title
   {
       get => (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
       set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
   }

   public object Value
   {
       get => GetValue(ValueProperty);
       set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(UserView), new PropertyMetadata(default));

   public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(UserView), new PropertyMetadata(default));
   ```
6. Открываем теперь `.xaml` файл и переносим туда вид.
7. В `UserControl` так просто не привязать данные, вот тут имя и может пригодиться. Задаем самому `UserControl` значение `x:Name`, а привязки меняем на `{Binding Title, ElementName=uc}` (`uc` - имя, заданное в `x:Name`).
8. Все, с контролом закончили. Возвращаемся в основной XAML и от куда забирали вид, меняем на `<local:UserView Title="{Binding Name}" Value="{Binding Age}"/>`? запускаем и радуемся результатом.

В итоге, весь наш изначальный XAML, с кучей дубликатов и тесной связью с C# кодом, превратился в простой и лаконичный:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:UserView Title="{Binding Name}" Value="{Binding Age}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Вот примерно такое у вас и должно быть.

Comment: Чтобы подсветить xaml, надо `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` через пустую строку перед кодом добавить.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, с этим разобрался. Появился еще вопрос: можно ли пойти еще дальше и сделать универсальный элемент для нескольких? Что я имею ввиду: тут у нас TextBox с названием, но у меня так же имеются и другие элементы (ComboBox, DatePicker...). Собственно можно сделать под каждый свой элемент (что в принципе правильно), но все таки интересно, как это можно реализовать в одном универсальном

Comment: @Дмитрий Это совершенно не верный подход к проектированию. Вот скажем, `DataPicker`, это что? Наверно это класс, который содержит в себе `DateTime` свойство. А `ComboBox`? Наверно это коллекция неких объектов, да еще и идентификатор того, что отображать, а также свойство "выделен сейчас". То есть, все это, совершенно разные объекты, с совершенно разной логикой, пихать все в одно место, это нарушение всех возможных правил программирования. Поэтому, это должно быть отдельными классами, а в XAML должно быть задано соответствие через [DataTemplate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1430956).

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое