# Таблица 10х10 с буквами в WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, алгоритм

Моя задача состоит в том, создать для начала таблицу 10х10 которая будет заполнена рандомными буквами от A - Z. Все это нужно реализовать с помщью WPF C#.

Пока что у меня только получилось построить таблицу вот сам код

```
 private void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        const int columWidth = 10;
        const int rowHeight = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < columWidth; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < rowHeight; j++)
            {
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
                r.Width = Zeichenfläche.ActualWidth / columWidth - 2.0;
                r.Height = Zeichenfläche.ActualHeight / rowHeight - 2.0;
                r.Fill = Brushes.Lavender;
                r.Stroke = Brushes.Magenta;
                Zeichenfläche.Children.Add(r);
                Canvas.SetLeft(r, j * Zeichenfläche.ActualWidth / columWidth);
                Canvas.SetTop(r, i * Zeichenfläche.ActualHeight / rowHeight);
                 r.MouseDown += R_MouseDown;
            }
        }
    }

    private void R_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Rectangle)sender).Fill = Brushes.Gray;
    }
```

Я создал прокто кнонку "Старта" и при нажатии на кнопку, я получаю таблицу. Сама таблица выглядит вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть рабочий код который генерирует рандомные буквы

```
Random rchar = new Random();
char[,] MyArray = new char[10,10];
for (int x = 0; x < MyArray.GetLength(0); ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < MyArray.GetLength(1); ++y)
    {                    
        MyArray[x, y] = (char)(rchar.Next(65, 91));
    }            
}
```

Но у меня не выходит вставить данные буквы в клетки которые в таблице. Помогите мне пожалуйста, это моя первая работа с WPF да и вообще я новчиок, по этому тяжело.

PS: Дальнейшая моя идея, создать массив из слов, которые потом поместить в таблицу и как бы эти слова нужно найти, нажать на буквы и что бы слово выводилось в консоль например

Comment: Не забывайте, что WPF это как минимум 2 слоя: XAML - ваш UI, вид приложения, и C# - код, данные, и все остальное. Эти слои связываются друг с другому Привязками (Binding). А теперь посмотрите на свой код, где у вас XAML? Где у вас привязки? А их нет, ибо вы тупо хардкодите через C# все, и интерфейс, и данные, все. А это очень плохо! Сделайте в XAML `ListBox` или `ItemsControl`, измените ему вид элемента на вложенный также `ListBox` или `ItemsControl`, который в свою очередь будет иметь вид ячейки. Дальше привяжите это к коллекции коллекций, и привяжите. Вот вам и весь проект.

Comment: большое спасибо за совет, но все что вы мне описали я не понял. можно ли описать как то по подробей что и как мне создавать с пощью XML либо может где то есть Видео урок или документация.

Answer (score 4):

Основы основ любого WPF проекта, это XAML и привязки, если вы их игнорируете, то у вас будет не проект, а каша, которую будет трудно развивать дальше, трудно поддерживать, и она даже будет медленней работать.

1. Задаем `DataContext` - это некое свойство контрола или окна, которое отвечает за то, от куда будут забираться данные для привязок. В нашем случае, мы делаем простой пример, без каких либо правил и прочего, а значит смело пишем в конструкторе `MainWindow`, после `InitializeComponent();` строку `DataContext = this;`.
2. Теперь нам нужна коллекция, которая будет хранить наши символы. Так, как у нас некая "матрица", то нам нужна коллекция с вложенной коллекцией. Если вы работаете с привязками, то для оповещения UI об изменении данных в коллекции, она должна реализовать интерфейс `INotifyCollectionChanged`, без него, если вы добавите/удалите что либо из коллекции, в UI вы это не увидите. Стандартными такими коллекциями в WPF являются `ObservableCollection<>` и `BindingList<>`, возьмем с вами первую. Также привязки доступны **только** к публичным свойствам, это тоже надо учитывать! В итоге, делаем в классе окна свойство:

   ```
   public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<char>> Chars { get; set; }
   ```
3. Далее надо заполнить эту коллекцию, тут уж сами возитесь как надо, но дам подсказку, если вы хотите потом собирать слова, то надо как минимум из списка слов брать все символы, а потом уже на их основе, случайно все расставлять, но это уже на вашей совести) Я пока возьму ваш код генерации и просто грубо переделаю его под коллекцию. В итоге весь наш код окна выглядит так:

   ```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<char>> Chars { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            Random rchar = new Random();
            Chars = new();
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            {
                Chars.Add(new());
                for (int y = 0;  y < 10; y ++)
                {
                    Chars[x].Add((char)rchar.Next(65, 91));
                }
            }

        }
    }
   ```

   Все очень просто, да?)
4. Имея данные, мы можем теперь делать UI. Что нам нужно? Хм, нам нужны кнопки, которые будут размещаться по столбцам и рядам, можем поступить как с коллекцией (коллекция внутри коллекции)? Да, можем, давайте сделаем:

   ```xml
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Chars}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button
                                Width="30"
                                Height="30"
                                Margin="3"
                                Content="{Binding}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
   ```

   Тут интересно может быть следующее:

   - `{Binding}` - это привязка, через которую мы задаем то свойство, которое нас интересует в классе, указанным как `DataContext`, без обозначения свойства мы привязываемся к объекту, а не к его свойству.
   - `ItemTemplate` - так мы переопределяем вид на нужный нам, где в первом случае мы задаем `ItemsControl`, а во втором видом у нас является простая кнопка.
   - `ItemsPanel` - задаем другую панель, которая разместит наши объекты не снизу вверх, а в один ряд.

Результатом у нас будет такое:

[image: Char Panel]

Спросите теперь как кликнуть и узнать, что за кнопка?
Когда вы привязываетесь, и хотите все сделать грамотно, то лучше использовать `ICommand`, ибо они для привязок и созданны. Но так, как вы новичек, лишним вас грузить не буду, а значит для нас подойдут простые `Click` события.

- Пишем у кнопки в XAML `Click="Button_Click"`
- В коде окна пишем обработчик:

  ```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Button button) 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Мы нажали на {button.Content}");
        }
    }
  ```

  `Debug.WriteLine()` - это вывод в консоль отладки, меняйте на свою логику.

Собственно, вот вам и весь ваш код, с привязками и всем, чем положено. Из замечаний, советую сразу начать понимать, что такое MVVM, избавляться от `Click`, кода в классе окна, и так далее. Также этот код можно переделать без вложенной коллекции в коллекцию и `ItemsControl` в `ItemsControl`, для этого вам понадобиться коллекция символов, без каких-либо уровней, а также `UniformGrid`. Вот вам уже "домашнее задание")

Ну и да, забудьте раз и на всегда про дергание контролов через имена в WPF проекте, вообще забудьте про `x:Name`, они вам нужны максимум для XAML стилей. Если вы делаете в C# коде `myControl.SomeProperty = ...;`, то вы сразу, автоматом должны понимать, что делаете что-то не то.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо за такое подробное объяснение.  Скажите для того что бы теперь поместить какие либо слова, а эти слова я создам с помощью массива searchinWords например.  Мне нужно будет создать новый метод который для начала и разбить слово по буквам. И как потом присвоить этим буквам место в таблице?

Comment: @Dima Это вопрос уже про массивы больше и генерацию, а не WPF. Тут моя задача была показать вам то, как работать с WPF проектом, а уже как заполнять массивы, это уже думайте сами) Да и я честно, без понятия как тут грамотно в массив засунуть слова, не, как бы слова засунуть это не проблема, находите нужный индекс от которого начинать, и заменяете буквы на нужные, но вам ведь надо еще и повороты небось сделать, чтоб слова не просто в линию шли, а некими зигзагами, а еще может и соединить несколько слов в одно целое, как в нормальном кроссворде, вот тут я честно не подскажу вам)

Comment: Нет для меня самая главная задача, что бы отображалась таблица с буквами и в ней были спрятаны для начала слова по вертикали или горизонтали.  И что бы я мог когда нашел слово буквы кликать и если слово было правильное оно светилось зеленым ))

Comment: @Dima Ну, как в массив закинуть слова я думаю разберетесь сами, а вот как подсветить... Для начала вам нужен класс, в котором вы пропишете нужные свойства (например: символ, выбран, решено), далее вы делаете коллекцию коллекций не `char`, а этих классов, заполняете, в XAML меняете привязки, ссылаясь на эти свойства (`Content="{Binding}"` -> `Content="{Binding Symbol}"`), привязываете цвет (почитайте про триггеры), и все, визуально у вас все готово. А сверять со словами, тут уже надо подумать, я бы наверно сделал массив слов, который содержал бы в себе индексы верных букв, и так проверял.

Comment: (Content="{Binding}"  А что делают это свойства ?

Comment: @Dima Яж написал в вопросе что это: `{Binding} - это привязка, через которую мы задаем то свойство, которое нас интересует в классе, указанным как DataContext, без обозначения свойства мы привязываемся к объекту, а не к его свойству.`. То есть вы так говорите UI: "Ей, возьми данные из указанного свойства и отобрази мне их. `Content` у кнопки, это стандартно то, что внутри у нее.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо. Я пока у меня есть время посмотрю уроки по WPF!

Comment: @Dima чтобы принять ответ, в случае если он был полезен, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Скажите а почему сама таблица не отображается в в окне MainWindow. Сама таблица с буквами поялвляеться только тогда когда я запускаю программу.

Comment: И еще не могу разобраться  у меняне работает код который вы мне дали. Где вы написали код для передачи данных кнопки кудамы нажали.  У меня горит красным button_content

Comment: как наблюдать за изменениями в релаьномвремени без запускнаие программы ??

Comment: @Dima не вижу никаких `button_content` в ответе. Код, о котором говорите, видите только вы. Про отладку можно почитать [здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-Ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger).

Comment: Я не правильно поставил вопрос. Как мне тперь добавить к этим кнопкам оброботчик событий? Что бы было видно кто куда нажимает ?

Comment: @Dima `не отображается в в окне` - если речь про окно отладки, то напишите в XAML окна следующее: `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:MainWindow},IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"`, таким образом будут использоваться в конструкторе **реальные** данные, которые автоматически подгрузятся из C# кода. НО, не стоит такое делать на больших проектах, ибо конструктор начнет сильно зависать, лучше сделайте [фейковые данные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/569974/220553), либо указать [демонстрационные данные](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-design-time-sample-data).

Comment: `У меня горит красным button_content` - смотрите внимательно мой ответ, я там такое не использовал. У вас должно быть `Click = "название_метода"`, где `название_метода` - это в классе окна `private void название_метода(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){}`. Когда вы пишете `Click = "..."` вам студия должна предложить что именно вы хотите сделать, там будет "создать обработчик", вот нажмите его и в C# коде будет все нужное. `к этим кнопкам оброботчик событий` - в вопросе про это уже есть ответ, читайте внимательно!

Comment: А спасибо получилось, у меня было не допонимание

Comment: @Dima Про данные в студии кстати - помните, WPF поддерживает изменение данных в реальном времени, это означает то, что вы можете запустить прям приложение, и с запущенным приложением менять XAML, он будет сразу меняться в окне вашего приложения. Как по мне это удобней, чем делать через конструктор студии)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ аааа та ладно, просто когда я пытался поместить весь грид по центру и прописывал в XAML   **HorizontalAlignment="Center"**  то приходилось запускать заново приложение что бы применилось

Comment: @Dima Если правильно работает горячая перезагрузка, то должно обновлять все в реальном времени, даже вот положение, как код выше. Главное, чтоб проект был запущен именно под отладкой из Visual Studio (зеленая стрелка, или F5 кнопка).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139935/discussion-between-dima-and-evgeniyz).